# How to set loading to false input is empty

Tags: angular

I am trying to set loading to false on form submission if the user didn't enter any values and the validators for required fields are executed, so that the loader goes away if the fields. Inside onSubmit i tried this but it doesnt work.

```
if(!this.loginForm.controls.email.value || !this.loginForm.controls.password.value) {
    console.log("empty");
    this.loading=false;
  }
```

It doesn't even print empty on the console

```
<form method="get" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div *ngIf="loading" class="loader-container">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
<div *ngIf="(loginError && loginForm.controls.email.touched) && (loginForm.controls.password.touched) " class="login-error">
   <span>Email or Password incorrect</span>
</div>
<input type="text" formControlName="email" name="email" (focus)="focusEmailInput()" placeholder="email *"/>
<input type="text" formControlName="password" (focus)="focusPasswordInput()" placeholder="Password *"/>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

ts file

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  loading: boolean;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private auth: AuthService, private route: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

 onSubmit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }

  if(!this.loginForm.controls.email.value) {
    console.log("empty");
    this.loading=false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking form with invalid condition in the `onSubmit()` function. since the form is invalid, the below code won't execute.So, check the invalid condition in the button itself.

Check the condition for the send button like below

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="onSubmit()">Send</button>

     onSubmit() {
            this.loading = true;
            this.submitted = true;

          if(!this.loginForm.controls.email.value) {
            console.log("empty");
            this.loading=false;
}
    }
```